# Unable to get needed informations for Apple Pay payment like email, Phone number , Street etc

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, applepay, passkit

- How to extract values like Email , Phone Number. I got billing and shipping addresses successfully. But , I couldn't get Email and Phone Numbers. Kindly suggest me programmatically ... (using kABPersonEmailProperty etc)

  - Also , in

    ```
      (void) paymentAuthorizationViewController:(PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController*)controller

           didSelectShippingAddress:(ABRecordRef)address
                         completion:(void (^)(PKPaymentAuthorizationStatus, NSArray *, NSArray *))completion
      {
                -------- // I am getting street property Nil. 
      }
    ```

All are suggesting to get from "didAuthorizePayment" , But i need to generate shipping prices dynamically on basis of "Street" ( Like POBox locations etc...). Suggest me solution for this case.

[image]

Comment: Apple promised all customers that nobody would ever get information about the paying. And please reformat your question...

Comment: @idmean, Not getting information regarding payment. Its needed basic customer informations which is required for Server processing. But I couldn't get that even ! :( - Re-phrased Qn :)

Answer (score 3):

You receive City and ZIP initially in the delegate callbacks. You are not provided with the full street address for shipping until after the user has authorized the payment with touch ID, for privacy reasons.

The same is true for e-mail and phone number. You can request them up-front, but they'll only be delivered to you *after* the user has touch ID'd the payment request. You then have an opportunity in your delegate callbacks to go and inspect the ABRecordRef, retrieve the information you need, and decide if you're still able to fulfill the order (if you are, you'd send the payment information up to your processor).

Comment: Thank you, How to do Delegate call back from didAuthorizePayment? also, Why unable to checkout in same build if I share in iTunes testflight?