Understanding NFC and Apple Pay for Email/Phone capture at POS Checkout
I am trying to develop a soln for my client where, they would like their customers to share their phone number or email id while they transact in their stores at the POS checkout.
Two scenarios:

When the Retail store doesn't have NFC enabled POS checkout

When the Retail Store has NFC enabled POS checkout that can accept Apple and Google Pay.


I am trying to stay away from having a customer enter their email or phone number on the POS device as those are bad UX and most don't do it.
I am looking for a solution where either by just a tap/faceID of their phone, they can be prompted to enter phone with a URL that opens up in the phone, or better if the POS is NFC enabled, can we show them a prompt as a second tap on their phone via Apple Pay?
Pls advise.

Probably technically possible but there are limitations and as there is no details about the POS hardware then it is difficult to say if it can do it.
Most NFC enabled phones (iOS included) will prompt the user to open a Web site address when they are brought in to range of a NFC Tag (real or emulated) given the right conditions.
The iOS documentation lays out the conditions, the most relevant one for you is that - Apple Pay Wallet is not in use.
Thus the flow would be.

The terminal is in POS mode.

The user presents the iPhone and a NFC payment transaction is completed.

The terminal swaps to emulating a NFC Tag with an Ndef URL payload on it.

The user closes Apple Pay Wallet.

The user presents their phone again to the terminal.

The phone background reads the Ndef URL and shows the notification

The user clicks to open a web browser and loads the site.

User enters their details to the website.


Which is probably more steps than entering their details directly on the terminals UI and probably a worse user experience.
Note that Android device also background read Ndef URL's under the right conditions.
Documentation on the Ndef URI Spec for the payload that needs to be emulated by the POS
As a variation to this flow the URL could be a Universal link which if configured correctly would prompt the user to open(or install from the App Store and open) your App.
If you App could automatic gather the data you need then your App could open a NFCTagReaderSession in response to being started by the Universal Link and then write that data back to the emulated Tag on the terminal (which it would need to be programmed to process).
But if the App is not able to gather the users details automatically then it would have to prompt the user to input them in to your App, so the first time they use it the user experience will be poor.

So, if I understand correctly, you are saying same NFC enabled POS terminal can also send a URL notification to a user device (on 2nd tap) which they can open on their mobile browser?
I thought NFC enabled POS for payments, aren't allowed to send URL and only other NFC tags on top of it can do?
Lastly, the flow, I was thinking was if a user goes to POS checkout, used Apple/GPay to pay, then, it prompts on the terminal if they would like loyalty discount etc, tap again to enter #/email, and when they tap again, it opens up a url on their mobile browser. Entering there is better

Second, It isn't possible to send a user email (attached to Apple ID) or # while they are doing Apple or Google Pay at the POS terminal? We can show them extra info of getting their email or # along with $ amount in pop up which comes up when you use tap or faceID, or is that prevented by Apple and Google at all during payment?

Also sorry for multiple comments, I am trying to comprehend your suggestions and I am a strategy/product person with background in AI. So less on the ios and Android space.
If I understand your answer correctly, you are suggesting 3 ways:


If user has store app installed, then app can automatically read NFC tags data and open up in forground for user with a URL/Message (enter your email/# etc).


If a user doesn't have app installed (which might be many), then the ios/Android device can silently read NFC tag in background and show a pop up


Universal Link?


Using NFC tags



This questions suggest one can extract email and phone number of a customer even during Apple Pay transaction?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29030671/unable-to-get-needed-informations-for-apple-pay-payment-like-email-phone-number?rq=3

Technically from the NFC side a lot of NFC hardware can be a reader/writer or Tag emulator, whether your POS can do this depends on the hardware it is run on and any other restrictions they have placed on the hardware. The POS is just being a reader/writer at the basic level, there is nothing in NFC that would prevent it swapping modes, there might be other restrictions. A loyalty card could supply the info, but that would need to be pre-created with the data before any NFC iteration.

The problem with your question is you seem to want to prompt the user to go to a URL to enter this information and NFC in the mode for Payments is not designed to do this, it is just designed to return pre stored information, payments details, loyalty card number (technically it does not need to be a number from a loyalty card). You have to be careful Apple and Google Pay support two different types of operation, In App billing where contact details might be need to send you stuff you have been billed for or NFC payment for external payment. Don't confuse the two different capabilities.

The problem seems is that as a POS manufacturer you should know all this, but most likely it seems that are programming on a generic terminal with POS hardware attached and your limited by what the POS hardware exposes to you via their API, I would read the API docs. You might be read the data from a loyalty card you got the user to pre-install. I don't believe there is anything in the EMV standard used for the payment transactions to do what you want, I don't know if NFC VAS protocol can help. To increase data entry rates offer a discount to provide this info on the terminal UI directly.

Thanks Andrew for comment. Actually, I don't want the user to enter something on their device via a URL that opens up. That was mentioned because my understanding was that typical NFC enabled POS devices at POS checkout of retail stores, don't have the capability to also transmit or read data (email/#) via Tap/FaceID.
I would prefer if just by tap or FaceID, a user can transmit their email or phone number if given some incentive (additional discount, digital receipt etc).
Also, if store doesnt have NFC enabled POS, was wondering if adding an NFC reader cheaply could help here

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Pinged you details on Chat.
